# Copy .txt files from a .tar.gz file to other directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to copy all the .txt files from a compressed file (this file has unknown_name_folders):
.txt files location ---> my_path/?unknown_name_folder?/file.txt
I want to do --->  my_path/file.txt

I did this code, but I have this error: EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached. Any idea?

```
file=my_path+"/"+fil
if file.endswith('.tar.gz'):

    tarf = tarfile.open(file, "r:gz")
    for info in tarf:

        if info.name.endswith('.txt'):
            print(info.name)

            tar = tarfile.open(file) #extracting
            tar.extractall()
            tar.close()    
            code=os.system('cp ' + my_path+'/'+info.name +' '+ file)
```

Comment: Don't you need the 'gz' flag while extracting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paulo mentioned, you missed off the "gz" flag the second time you opened the tar file. Also, your target for copying the file was the original tarball - I assume you wanted it in a separate directory ("targdir" here)

You only need to extract the contents once, so the code becomes:

```
file=my_path+"/"+fil
targdir='dest'
if file.endswith('.tar.gz'):

    tarf = tarfile.open(file, "r:gz")
    tarf.extractall()
    for info in tarf:

        if info.name.endswith('.txt'):
            print(info.name)
            code=os.system('cp ' + info.name +' '+ targdir)
```

(edit - you don't need 'mypath' in the "cp" command - you have extracted the tarball into the current directory, so "info.name! is the full path to the file)

Comment: You could also look at the shutil library which contains many shell utilities, including copying files. so add "from shutil import copy2" and then copy the file with "copy2(info.name, targdir)"